# Strange echo, print behaviour in PHP?

Tags: php, printing, echo

The following code outputs `43211`, why?

```
  echo print('3').'2'.print('4');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your statement parses *to humans* as follows.

Echo a concatenated string composed of:

1. The result of the function `print('3')`, which will return true, which gets stringified to `1`
2. The string '2'
3. The result of the function `print('4')`, which will return true, which gets stringified to `1`

Now, the order of operations is really funny here, that can't end up with `43211` at all!  Let's try a variant to figure out what's going wrong.

```
echo '1' . print('2') . '3' . print('4') . '5';
```

This yields `4523111`

PHP is parsing that, then, as:

```
echo '1' . (print('2' . '3')) . (print('4' . '5'));
```

Bingo!  The `print` on the left get evaluated first, printing `'45'`, which leaves us

```
echo '1' . (print('2' . '3')) . '1';
```

Then the left `print` gets evaluated, so we've now printed `'4523'`, leaving us with

```
echo '1' . '1' . '1';
```

Success.  `4523111`.

Let's break down your statement of weirdness.

```
echo print('3') . '2' . print('4');
```

This will print the `'4'` first, leaving us with

```
echo print('3' . '2' . '1');
```

Then the next print statement is evaluated, which means we've now printed `'4321'`, leaving us with

```
echo '1';
```

Thus, `43211`.

**I would highly suggest not `echo`ing the result of a `print`, nor `print`ing the results of an `echo`.  Doing so is highly nonsensical to begin with.**

---

Upon further review, I'm actually not entirely sure how PHP is parsing either of these bits of nonsense.  I'm not going to think about it any further, it hurts my brain.

Comment: +1 I'd add that the language construct `print` doesn't get evaluated the same way functions do, hence the weird order. I'd almost go as far as saying that this nesting produces more or less undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, I'd like to thank you for this VERY illuminating answer.

Comment: Almost right - print is a language construct. The parentheses are ignored by the language. print(3) . '2'; is the same thing as print 3 . '2';

Comment: _The print on the left get evaluated first_. It is right one which is executing first.

Answer (score 3):

Much of the confusion is due to the placement of parentheses around the arguments to `print`. As you know, parentheses are optional with language constructs; what you probably didn't know is that they're removed during parsing.

**Evaluation order**

Let's remove the parentheses first:

```
echo print '3' . '2' . print '4';
```

And illustrate the actual order of evaluation:

```
echo (print ('3' . '2' . (print '4')))
^     ^      ^                     ^
3     2      1--------->>----------1
```

In the heart of this you will find a concatenation of strings or string representations; this is evaluated first:

```
'3' . '2' . (print '4')
```

The first two elements are concatenated:

```
'32' . (print '4')
```

Then, the value of `(print '4')` is evaluated; after printing its argument `'4'`, the return value of `print` itself is always `int(1)`; this is cast into a string `'1'` and concatenated with the other elements:

```
'321'
```

This concludes the first step. The second step passes the temporary results to another `print` statement:

```
print '321'
```

As before, `'321'` is printed and now `int(1)` is returned for the last step:

```
echo 1
```

**Proof**

You can confirm this behaviour when you look at the opcodes that are generated (output column is added for clarity):

```
line     # *  op          return  operands        output
------------------------------------------------+-------
   1     0  >   CONCAT      ~0      '3', '2'    |
         1      PRINT       ~1      '4'         | 4
         2      CONCAT      ~2      ~0, ~1      | 4
         3      PRINT       ~3      ~2          | 4321
         4      ECHO        ~3                  | 43211
```

*Explanation*

- `"3"` and `"2"` are concatenated - `"32"` - and stored into `~0`.
- `"4"` is printed and the return value `int(1)` is stored into `~1`.
- `~0` and `~1` are concatenated - `"321"` - and stored into `~2`.
- `"321"` is printed and the return value is stored into `~3`.
- `int(1)` is printed as `"1"` due to string casting.

Answer (score 2):

`print` is returning `1`

On the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

> Return Values: Returns 1, always.

You should just probably stick to using `echo`.

Comment: I still don't understand why does it output in that order (43211)?

Comment: @Tunji Gbadamosi Please see [Charles' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340330/strange-echo-print-behaviour-in-php/3340367#3340367).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function within a function as alex said. Just simply use echo or print.

```
echo '3'.'2'.'4';
```

will return properly or likewise for print.

Comment: `print` technically is a language construct.

Comment: Yes, it's generally only more useful if you are looking for a return value upon the completion. But for something as simple as this it would work nearly the same; minus the retval of course that print would give and echo would not. In extreme cases, echo is probably faster.