# print behavior php

Tags: php

Below is something strange, I didn't get

```
if (print("foo") || print("bar")) {
  // "foo" has been printed.
}
```

Why the output is `1`?

Could please explain?

Comment: possible (not-exact-but-close-enough) duplicate of [Strange echo, print behaviour in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340330/strange-echo-print-behaviour-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because PHP is a ridiculous language. `print` is not a normal function, it's a language construct. This line is actually parsed as:

```
if (print (("foo") || print("bar")))
```

And `("foo") || print("bar")` is an expression which evaluates to `1`. The string `"foo"` in a boolean context is true, so the `||` operator yields `1`.

If you explicitly parenthesize the expression the way one would expect it to be parsed:

```
if ((print("foo")) || (print("bar")))
```

Then the output is what you would expect:

```
foo
```

Comment: The bottom line is that checking the return value of `print` is nonsensical.  In fact, *giving* `print` a return value was nonsensical.  Where's my time machine?  I need to go back and sledgehammer someone.

Comment: `so the || operator yields 1.` *without* printing "bar" due to logic shortcut.