# php print inside print - what's the result

Tags: php, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange echo, print behaviour in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340330/strange-echo-print-behaviour-in-php)

The following PHP code:

```
print (2).(3 * (print 3));
```

displays "`323`" to the output? How is it processed?

Comment: it's similar, but not the same, e.g. print(print) is not the same as echo(print).

Comment: Doesn't matter; never do something that works with the value of `print`, as doing so is nonsensical.  The code you've written here should not exist because it does something pathologically incorrect.

Comment: @Charles: above comment is not about "should we use print return value or not" but about possible duplicate ;-)
besides, you can have such question in a PHP test. And then it doesn't matter whether such code should exist or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the brackets (operation precedence) - the

```
(print 3)
```

in the end of the line displays the first digit of the final output (3), but all PHP print statements return 1. Always (check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)). So after this, we've got:

```
print (2).(3 * 1);
```

which is the same as:

```
print (2).(3);
```

Now it's just a simple concatenation which will output "23". So we've got "323" displayed.

Note that

```
print (2).(1 - (print 3));
```

would display "320".

Comment: just to point out the difference between print and echo - echo returns void and replacing print with echo will throw error.